# What is expected QGIS 2.2 release date?

Tags: qgis-2.2

What is the expected QGIS 2.2 release date?

It would be helpful to schedule my custom development in QGIS for "Relations" management.

Comment: google: "qgis 2.2 release", first result. Easy!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See the [QGIS development roadmap](http://www.qgis.org/en/site/getinvolved/development/index) which indicates that the week ending 21 February 2014 is being targeted.

Answer (score 3):

February 21, 2014 is the release date